# My bootstrap style is not rendering prperly in my spring mvc application

Tags: spring, hibernate

Iam developing a E-musicstore application using spring mvc and hibernate.When I add `header.jsp` file to my `ViewproductList.Jsp` file The page is not rendering my bootstrap style properly.

my dispatcher servlet configuration

[image]

this is how its displayed in browser

[image]

Comment: Please post the content of your configuration file as text and not as an image (screenshot). The text in the screenshot is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Interceptor -->


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mymusic" />

</beans:beans>
```

Try this... if you face same issue, please attatch your brower's `NETWORK` Tab which i can see HTTP information.